# How to convert different units to one?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns: one is the amount of money the other one is unite : per day, per week, per month and per year how I can make all of them per day?

Data:

```
   PAYPR         UNIT
    40       (4) Per month
    100      (5) Per semester
    50       (6) Per year
    5        (1) Per day
```

I know if it was just 2 units:  "(4) Per month", "(1) Per day" I could do this :

```
  with(df, ifelse(UNIT != '(4) Per month', PAYPR * 30, PAYPR))
```

output:

```
   PAYPR         UNIT               uniqe
    40       (4) Per month          40*30
    100      (5) Per semester       100*90
    50       (6) Per year           50*360
    5        (1) Per day            5*1
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output.  e.g values for `semester'

Comment: Is the year a regular year or a leap year?  They don't have the same number of days.  Also, what defines a month here?

Comment: This does not seem to be a well formed problem.  Not all months, semesters or years have the sme number of days.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen month =30*value,  year=360*value, semester= 90*value

Comment: OK, honestly for such a small data set I would probably just manually add a new column which maps the units to a common unit.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is just a sample , I have 5000 rows

Comment: @G5W I do not have more option, these details are not included in data set

Comment: Can you show us what more sample data would look like?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is the same as above , just different numbers! what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `case_when` from the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(unique = PAYPR * case_when(UNIT == "(4) Per month" ~ 30, 
                                    UNIT == "(5) Per semester" ~ 90,
                                    UNIT == "(6) Per year" ~ 360,
                                    UNIT == "(1) Per day" ~ 1))
```

Comment: how about if I want to divide by 60?

Comment: Then you multiply with 1/60

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to create a key/val dataset and join.  Note that this can be extended to any number of entries

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
df2 <- data.frame(key = c("month", "semester", "year", "day"),
      val = c(30, 90, 360, 1))
regex_left_join(df1, df2, by = "UNIT") %>% 
    mutate(uniqe = PAYPR *val) %>%
   select(PAYPR, UNIT = UNIT.x, uniqe)
#  PAYPR             UNIT uniqe
#1    40    (4) Per month  1200
#2   100 (5) Per semester  9000
#3    50     (6) Per year 18000
34     5      (1) Per day     5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(PAYPR = c(40L, 100L, 50L, 5L), UNIT = c("(4) Per month", 
"(5) Per semester", "(6) Per year", "(1) Per day")), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```